# Xcode swift: How to disable a button and re enable 24h later?

Tags: swift, button, time, uibutton

How can I disable a button and re enable it after 24h?

I want the button in my app to be tapped A max of 3 counts every 24h (even if user quit app and reopen it, or even delete app and re download, how can I proceed? Any suggestion?

I need help!!!

Max

Comment: my best guess would be probably by using a server. If you just implement that in your code and works, think of what will happen if the user changes his time from settings... You need the connection to a server to verify that the time is correct. Keep that in mind

Comment: Korpel, how can i use a server with my app, cause yes you are right, thats what i need.

Comment: It doesn't need a server. You can keep the unlock date in keychain. this way even if the app gets deleted, the info will be available. Plus, it's more secure!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your local data storage looks like, but you can store an NSNumber (for # of times tapped) and NSDate in a plist (or NSUSerDefaults). When you load your app, you can read the NSNumber and NSDate, and depending on these values, you can enable or disable the button.

If you want it to save the information after the user deletes the app, you'll have to store it in iCloud Key Value data storage or something.

Comment: I wanna use real-time so I need to connect my app to a server can parse do that for me?